# What is the probability that all numbers in a set P are unique and each number in P is chosen randomly between 1 and n^3?

Tags: pr.probability

Hope someone can help me answer this question.

The problem is described as below.

I want to form a set (P) of n numbers. I randomly choose a number between 1 and n^3 and I choose n times.

My question is that what is the probability that all entries in P are unique and how can I get the probability?

Answer (score 0):

The magic words are "birthday paradox".